# Generating PDF files with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation

I’m trying to convert XML data into PDF files from a web page and I was hoping I could do this entirely within JavaScript. I need to be able to draw text, images and simple shapes. I would love to be able to do this entirely in the browser.

Answer (score 546, accepted):

I've just written a library called [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) which generates PDFs using Javascript alone. It's still very young, and I'll be adding features and bug fixes soon. Also got a few ideas for workarounds in browsers that do not support Data URIs. It's licensed under a liberal MIT license.

I came across this question before I started writing it and thought I'd come back and let you know :)

[Generate PDFs in Javascript](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Example create a "Hello World" PDF file.

```js
// Default export is a4 paper, portrait, using milimeters for units
var doc = new jsPDF()

doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10)
doc.save('a4.pdf')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did I partially inspire jsPDF? I learned about jsPDF the day you announced it. Looking great so far.

I ended up going with Prawn as it's easily the best PDF generation library out there for my requirements. I would still love to do all of my work in-browser as I'm not positive I'll get Ruby on the system I'm deploying to.

I'm watching jsPDF very closely. I would love to help out but my time is very limited. That might change in the future.

Comment: You did inspire it somewhat :), I was looking around on the internet to see if it already existed and saw that some people would find it useful. Let me know if you'd like to help out. I'm @MrRio on twitter.

Comment: does not have image embedding as far as I know.

Comment: This seems to work only in Chrome. FF8 and IE9 did not run this code

Comment: It's still very much alive. 0.9.0rc2 Released today.

Comment: @JamesHall, I'd like to thank you for all the work it must be taking to write this, and for MIT licensing it to make the world a better place when you could have commercialized it for your own gain.

Comment: A huge drawback: it does not support UTF-8. So, russian, czech or chinese texts wont work!

Comment: another big drawback i guess is no support for CSS, fonts etc. I mean for a dynamically created div how would i know which line will have which font? so I have used CSS. but it seems this lib can not read that.

Comment: When will it be possible to save a div with css as a pdf? For a project at work I need to include piecharts and such. Any possibility with this library?

Comment: Can downvoters offer us their "better" ideas or solutions? This is an excellent effort.

Comment: @JamesHall but what about css issues..this plugin doesn't support even inline css

Comment: Absolutely abysmal documentation all around. On top of this, the public api is not visible anywhere. 

Comment: chrome crashes when clubbed with html2canvas for huge html file  !

Comment: jsPDF serious need a better documentation

Comment: @JamesHall wondering if this partially implements the PDF spec, or how much of it you covered.

Comment: tried it, it walls with call stack exceeded for a 150kb txt file

Comment: We've been working with JsPDF and autotables which is nice but unfortunately it really doesn't work very well with UTF 8 characters, we were able to add custom fonts but it's very unstable, sometimes work sometimes doesn't for reasons that are not possible to figure out clearly

Comment: How do you resize text or do h1s or add css James?

Answer (score 167):

Another javascript library worth mentioning is **pdfmake**.

- [pdfmake playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html)
- [pdfmake on github](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake)

The browser support does not appear to be as strong as jsPDF, nor does there seem to be an option for shapes, but the options for formatting text are more advanced then the options currently available in jsPDF.

Comment: This answer should be upvoted a lot more, pdfmake is so much more robust than jspdf. However just a side note, it is wrapper around PDFKit library.

Comment: another side note, jspdf doesn't have utf-8 support and pdfmake has utf-8 support only for default fonts.

Comment: "pdfmake.min.js - 0.1.22 - 9 hours ago" It is not dead, updated this day.

Comment: From comparing the two playgrounds, to me it seems that jsPDF is more targeted at "graphic" PDF creation, whereas pdfmake is targeted more at generating well-formatted "plain" documents, it seems to have a lot more options for generic text formatting.

Comment: Is this IE friendly?

Answer (score 77):

I maintain [PDFKit](http://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit), which also powers pdfmake (already mentioned here). It works in both Node and the browser, and supports a bunch of stuff that other libraries do not:

- Embedding subsetted fonts, with support for unicode.
- Lots of advanced text layout stuff (columns, page breaking, full unicode line breaking, basic rich text, etc.).
- Working on even more font stuff for advanced typography (OpenType/AAT ligatures, contextual substitution, etc.). Coming soon: see the fontkit branch if you're interested.
- More graphics stuff: gradients, etc.
- Built with modern tools like browserify and streams. Usable both in the browser and node.

Check out http://pdfkit.org/ for a full tutorial to see for yourself what PDFKit can do. And for an example of what kinds of documents can be produced, check out the docs as a PDF [generated](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/blob/master/docs/generate.coffee) from some Markdown files using PDFKit itself: http://pdfkit.org/docs/guide.pdf.

You can also try it out interactively in the browser here: http://pdfkit.org/demo/browser.html.

Comment: Isn't this a server side library? I think the discussion is on the client side js library.

Comment: PDFKit works in both Node and the browser as mentioned in the answer. See the link to a browser demo.

Comment: Does this compress images? I am working on a web app that functions similar to camscanner and I am looking for PDF creation through javascript to leverage the compression and multi page format.

Comment: @devongovett can you look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190357/pdfkit-browser-uncaught-referenceerror-fs-is-not-defined-when-using-custom) about your library?

Comment: I've been using PDFKit recently and although it has a few glitches it does work well and is very solid. I would recommend it.

Answer (score 14):

Another interesting project is [texlive.js](http://manuels.github.io/texlive.js/).

It allows you to compile (La)TeX to PDF in the browser.

Comment: The hello world example renders nicely but takes around 30s to complete.

Answer (score 8):

For react fans there is another great resource for PDF generation: [React-PDF](https://react-pdf.org/)

It is great for creating PDF files in React and even let the user download them from the client side itself with no server required!

this is a small example snippet of React-PDF to create a 2 section PDF file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Page, Text, View, Document, StyleSheet } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

// Create styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4'
  },
  section: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    flexGrow: 1
  }
});

// Create Document Component
const MyDocument = () => (
  <Document>
    <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>Section #1</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>Section #2</Text>
      </View>
    </Page>
  </Document>
);
```

This will produce a PDF document with a single page. Inside, two different blocks, each of them rendering a different text. These are not the only valid primitives you can use. you can refer to the [Components](https://react-pdf.org/components) or [Examples](https://react-pdf.org/repl) sections for more information.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth mentioning [PDF-LIB](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) which is an awesome library:

- Supports **pure JavaScript**.
- Can **edit existing PDF templates** even with pure JavaScript. (Most impotently. Many JavaScript libraries can't do it)
- It is generating a PDF with **select-able/copy-able/highlight-able** text not an image file inside an PDF like many other libraries generate.
- More easy to use. (I love it)
  [image]
- If you are interested in using it with **pure JavaScript** [this may
  help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74958171/how-to-use-hopding-pdf-lib-with-pure-javascript-without-using-a-package-mana).
- If you are interested to do the same with the most popular JavaScript
  library as of now **JSPDF** [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74938273/edit-and-existing-pdf-template-with-parallax-jspdf). (Simply JSPdf can't do most **time saving** thing we want, **editing an existing template**.)

See how pretty the code is

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
        async function downloadPdf() {

            const url = './print-templates/pquot-template.pdf';
            const existingPdfBytes = await fetch(url).then(res => res.arrayBuffer());

            // Getting the document
            const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes);

            // Getting the first page
            const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();
            const firstPage = pages[0];

            // Customer name
            firstPage.drawText('Customer name is here with more text (GAR004) quick brown customerm jumps over lazy dog.', {
                x: 10.5*9,
                y: 76.6*9,
                size: 10,
                maxWidth: 28*9, // Wrap text with one line. WOW :O
                lineHeight: 1.5*9
            });

            // Currency short code
            firstPage.drawText('LKR', {
                x: 10.5*9,
                y: 73.5*9,
                size: 10
            });

            var itemName = 'Here is the item name with some really really long text and quick brown fox jumps over lazy dog. long text and quick brown fox jumps over lazy dog:)';
            // Item name
            firstPage.drawText(itemName, {
                x: 5*9,
                y: 67*9,
                size: 10,
                maxWidth: 31*9,
                lineHeight: 2*9
            });

            const pdfDataUri = await pdfDoc.saveAsBase64({ dataUri: true });
            document.getElementById('pdf').src = pdfDataUri;
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: As of today, it says the last version 1.17.1 has been released on Nov 7, 2021. It seems that it is not maintained any more... This may cause a problem if some security scan detects vulnerable dependencies (outdated versions). Also, it does not seem that bugs are fixed any more. Oh the joys of OSS that everyone uses (including big corps) but the maintainer(s) can't make a living off of it, even partially. (Yes, one could possibly fork and maintain, but is that worth it if PDF generation is only a small part of your work life?)

Comment: I'm confused - this is linking to jsPDF the same as the top answer. Have they been merged or something?