# window.location.href doesn't work at IE9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, window.location

Hi I save a canvas with the following codes.

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
window.location.href = img;
```

However IE9 doesn't work. Can not open data:image/octet-stream;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAA.....

How can I make it work at IE9?
Thanks for your helps...

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405345/data-uri-scheme-and-internet-explorer-9-errors

Answer (score 0):

may be try using

```
window.location.assign(img); // or
window.location = img;
```

for more details check [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location)