# window.open not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, csv, internet-explorer-10, window.open

I'm trying to convert json to csv, based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130849/convert-json-format-to-csv-format-for-ms-excel/4130939#4130939). Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox except IE10. `Window.open` doesn't seem to work in IE10.

```
window.open( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(str));
```

where `str` is my csv string

A new blank tab is opened with `url "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,xxxxxxxxxxxx"`
where `"xxxx"` is the encoded csv string.
I have also tried:

```
var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(str);
var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.href = uri;
downloadLink.download = "OpHis.csv";
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
```

with same result working in Chrome, Firefox but not in IE10. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check your browser's console for any errors

Comment: By the way, the `download` attribute/property isn't supported until IE11, so that's why your second snippet doesn't work: http://caniuse.com/download

Comment: Here's my example: http://jsfiddle.net/FZZvs/ , and this is the warning I get: `HTML1524: Invalid DOCTYPE. The shortest valid doctype is "<!DOCTYPE html>". 
unknownprotocol.htm, line 1 character 1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data URI scheme and Internet Explorer 9 Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405345/data-uri-scheme-and-internet-explorer-9-errors)

Comment: same behavior the url is data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,asdf%2Cfdsa%2Casdf

Comment: Yeah, that was my point. I just wanted to provide an example to test. According to my last comment about being a duplicate, this doesn't seem possible in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved my problem on ie10

```
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, 'msSaveBlobOrOpenBlob_testFile.txt');
```

you can find more information on this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx