# How do I download base64 document in IE9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

`IE9` not support to download uri link.

```
// it is not work in IE9
document.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
//window.open(uri + base64(format(template, ctx)));
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cmewv/1027/)

Please help me how to download file in IE9.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data URI scheme and Internet Explorer 9 Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405345/data-uri-scheme-and-internet-explorer-9-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great! I found the best solution for the "Data URI scheme and Internet Explorer 9 Errors"

below api support IE9, I could make a document from client-side.

https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify