# How can I use the data URI in internet explorer as a URL?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, notepad

The code I'm trying to use is

```
data:text/html,
<body contenteditable style="font: 2rem/1.5 monospace;
                             max-width:60rem;
                             margin:0 auto;
                             padding:4rem;">
```

I found it on a webiste. I'm suppose to just place it on the URL and hit enter but only for Chrome, Firefox and Opera. It won't work on IE. How can I make a notepad on IE?

More info:
Im using a work pc and I can't access any website nor programs. No file explorer, right click context menu, only has IE.

Comment: what exactly is that code, and what exactly you want to do? test a website or what?

Comment: What does Notepad have to do with this?

Comment: If you place that code on the address bar on a new tab it turns your tab into a notepad. You can write on the page. It works for Chrome Firefox and Opera but not on Internet Explorer it just gives an error. Im just want to know if there's a way to do this on IE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405345/data-uri-scheme-and-internet-explorer-9-errors `For security reasons, data URIs are restricted to downloaded resources. Data URIs cannot be used for navigation, for scripting, or to populate frame or iframe elements.`

Comment: You're missing a close `>` btw.  It didn't work until chrome until I added that character to the end

Comment: This answer is a solution I think - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16409572/1366216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Data URIs:** Internet Explorer does not support [data URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Data URIs For security reasons, Data URIs are restricted to downloaded resources. Data URIs cannot be used for navigation, for scripting, or to populate frame or iframe elements.
2. **REM CSS:** The CSS3 rem, which is always relative only to the root html element, is too new to rely on. As of July 2012, around [75% of all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=rem) in use support the rem.

Reference Link:

- [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)
- [Contenteditable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533690%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [CSS3 Rem Attribute](http://caniuse.com/#search=rem)
- [Data URI Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs)

**Conclusion:**
Please refer to the first link to achieve this as IE not started supporting it.

- <strike>IE doesn't support Data URI tag. Hence you have to use it in javascript or in html tag.</strike>
- <strike>IE doesn't support REM CSS3 Attribute rem as a unit. Hence you have to use em or px instead.</strike>

Comment: Im trying to open a data URI in a new tab which is well under 32 KB but it wont render.Im trying to extract a canvas chart as PNG

Comment: You've misinterpreted that link. Internet Explorer **does** support `data:` URIs, but not as places to link to.

Comment: @Quentin At the time of answer in 2014, Internet browser doesn't support in 2014.

Comment: @rajeshujade — Support for `data:` scheme URLs hasn't changed since before that answer. The last version of Internet Explorer was released in 2013.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using the javascript engine to create a similar execution.

---

**From the URL bar:**

```
javascript:window.document.write('<body contenteditable style="font: 2em/1.5 monospace;max-width:60em;margin:0 auto;padding:4em;">');
```

*If you copy and paste you will need to manually type **javascript:** in front of it since the browser trims that part of on paste.*

---

**If you want to execute a new window as an editor then try this:**

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var myWindow = window.open("", "MyEditorWindow");
        myWindow.document.write("<body contenteditable style=\"font: 2em/1.5 monospace;padding:40px;\">");
}
</script>
```

Check out this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nw0ttsft/)