# Any way to detect URI schema is available in windows using JavaScript in IE

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, uri, launching-application

I found few ways to detect where window support current URI scheme for Firefox and Chrome browser, if application not registered i will download and register those application uri

**Chrome**

```
 var appWindow = window.open('alert:"Hello%20World"',"_self");
 if(appWindow!=null){alert("it is worked")}
```

**Firefox**

```
 $("body").append('<span id="__protoProxy"></span>');

function queryWord(aWord)
{
 var protoProxy = document.getElementById('__protoProxy');
 if (protoProxy)
 {   
  var word = aWord.replace('"','\"');
  protoProxy.innerHTML = '<div style="display:none;"><iframe id="iframe01" src="alert://'+ word + '"></iframe></div>';
 }
}
queryWord('hello world');
if(document.getElementById('iframe01').contentDocument.body.innerHTML!=""){alert("it is worked")}
```

**IE**

but in IE i am unable to perform this action even though URI is not registered in windows, IE open window to select app from windows store.

Is there any way to detect in IE ?

Is there any way to detect it commonly across all browser ?

How does citrix launcher works in all browser?

Answer (score 0):

This question appears to be a duplicate, however since there is a bounty I receive an error that it cannot be closed.

In any case, check out this thread and see if it works for you.

[Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123313/detect-if-browser-supports-data-uri-scheme-with-iframes)