# Add line break in description field of yahoo calendar api

Tags: javascript, calendar, yahoo-api

I am trying to add a link to yahoo calendar events like this

```
https://calendar.yahoo.com/?v=60&DESC=Client%20Info%3A<br>Name%3A%20Hello%20World<br>&ST=20180630T070000&DUR=0100
```

But event description is appearing in same line. Other things are alright. Can anyone suggest how can I add line breaks in `DESC` so that it looks like this

```
Client Info
Name: Hello World
```

PS: Same description works fine in google calendar api.

Answer (score 0):

To break a line use `%0d%0a` (encoded CRLF or `\r\n`) or `%0a` (encoded LF or `\n`).

Example:

```
https://calendar.yahoo.com/?v=60&st=st20201231T193000&DUR=0200&desc=With%20clowns%0aand%20stuff&in_loc=North%20Pole
```

For more details you can check this document: https://github.com/InteractionDesignFoundation/add-event-to-calendar-docs/blob/master/services/yahoo.md