# Adding a comment box to a web page

Tags: jquery, angularjs, pdf, charts, highcharts

**Applicaton Background:**
I am developing an application that should have multiple highcharts on the same page with export to PDF button.On the left navigation there would be links to go to any high chart and a text area to enter user comments.Suppose we have three high charts that is bar chart,heat map and scatter plot on th esame page.If user wants to navigate to any of this chart then he must click on the links on the left navigation.The left navigation part will be available to each of the chart so that user can navigate to any chart.

**Query:**
When user clicks on export to PDF button,all the three charts should be exported in the PDF.Also comments in the text area should be exported as a note in the PDF.Please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

First you need some logic to convert this highchart to binary image

[Save highchart as binary image](http://angulartutorial.blogspot.in/2014/03/save-highchart-as-binary-image.html)

Then you have to take content and binary code for generating  pdf

That you can refer here

[Is it possible to generate PDF using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490028/is-it-possible-to-generate-pdf-using-jquery)

[Export HTML page to PDF on user click using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786113/export-html-page-to-pdf-on-user-click-using-javascript)

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-generate-pdf-file-in-jquery
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/html-to-pdf

Better use some server side logic to generate pdf

Answer (score 0):

I advice to familiar with the related topic http://www.highcharts.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions#export-multiple