# Jquery for pdf generation

Tags: jquery, database, pdf

I fetched the data from database, then I need to generate a pdf by clicking a hyperlink. This clicking event should be in JQuery. I don't have any idea to write the code.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried ?

Comment: You should check this,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490028/is-it-possible-to-generate-pdf-using-jquery

Comment: No, I didn't tried any thing. Just give the idea, how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Sivakesav Parikala you can create pdf at client side using the jsPDF plugin.

Below is the sample code for the same

**HTML :**

```
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
```

**JS :**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    var doc = new jsPDF();

    $('#cmd').click(function () {
        doc.text(35, 25, "Praksh loves jsPDF");
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    });
});
```

Please find the demo for the same JSFiddle : 
https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/so2rxpzu/

For more details on the plugin please visit : https://parall.ax/products/jspdf