# How to generate PDF using HTML5 and JavaScript 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf-generation, html5-canvas

I have a project in HTML5, I have used canvas in it. I want to export the content of the canvas to a PDF file.

Can anyone suggest how can I do that using either JavaScript or jQuery or any other JavaScript library?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript

rgds

Comment: do you use any php code in your project... if yes you can use dompdf which is an open source script

Answer (score 6):

Try this : http://jspdf.com/ 
It is a HTML5 JavaScript PDF generation library.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.