# Extract images from a PDF file with JQuery and create thumbnails

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I want to extract many images from a large PDF and then display those images as thumbnails. 
Right now we are using TallComponents.PDF dll for accomplished this task, but it takes much time to extract images and need to create some separate automation to reduce overhead from web server.

Is there any Jquery plugin i can use to extract images from PDF which may be fast enough and extract images on th fly.

Thanks for all your help..

Comment: js is for DOM (HTML) manipulation, not anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any Jquery plugin i can use to extract images from PDF which
>   may be fast enough and extract images on th fly.

None that I am aware of. PDF manipulation is always a difficult and expensive task that is better done on the server.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a JavaScript library it's not intended to address this issue.

It can get you data from a server, but it can't generate images from a PDF, even though there are some JS libs out their, which can generate PDFs … But they dont work in all browsers and they're not generating images …

See this thread: [Generating PDF files with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript)

Have you tried to use ImageMagick for thumbnail generation? I got good results out of it and it was really fast too.

- [ImageMagick usage under Windows](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/windows/)
- [Use ImageMagick for PDF thumbnails (Linux)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=536874)