# sencha touch pdf generation form client side

Tags: sencha-touch, pdf-generation, itext

We are working on creating mobile app using sencha touch frame work. one of our requirements is when user hits view pdf, the user entered form details which stored locally has json format should be rendered and view as pdf and also it can be saved as a pdf locally.
i found that itext is one of the java library which is widely used for pdf generation. but i couldn't find any article inter relating both sencha touch and itext. let me know is that a possible way or any other method available for json to pdf generation in sencha touch.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

java has nothing to do with javascript.

A quick Google search of "javascript pdf generation" lists some libraries that may work but getting them to run on a device might be more trouble than its worth id look at submitting the form results to a server and downloading the resultant PDF.

this might point you in the right direction:
[generating-pdf-files-with-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript)