# PDF generation using iTextG in Sencha + Cordova app using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, pdf-generation, itext

We have a Sencha + Cordova app for Android that should generate a PDF document. We are considering iText for PDF generation. Is it possible to achieve this? I understand that it is possible to trigger Java code with a JavaScript interface. So having a JS interface trigger the PDF generation code in Java should work (theoritically). Has anyone done this before please?

Yes I have had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659237/sencha-touch-pdf-generation-form-client-side) but our requirement is that the app should be a standalone with no server back end.