# Generating pdf reports with javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, d3.js

I'm attempting to generate pdf reports based on selected parameters on a webpage via javascript. I'm using D3 to generate charts and it would amazing to have those same charts appear on a pdf. In searching for a solution I came across this:

[Generating PDF files with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript)

jsPDF seems like a possible solution. I was wondering if there are any best practices in pdf report generation from a webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3 charts are SVG charts, injecting SVG into PDF can be done with various XSL FO technologies. You could run a web service XSL FO formatting solution and send the content with SVGs inside to it and format to PDF.