# EmberJs Calculate the total amount

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm beginner in Emberjs,

I want to calculate the total amount in the added item list.

For example:

```
(03) items added in list
------------------------
Item-1  3,000.00
Item-2  4,000.00
Item-3  3,000.00
-------------------------
Total  10,000.00    Print
-------------------------
```

**How to create the view and controller in emberjs for calculate the total amount?**

**How to create the PDF file and print the same output as PDF format?**

Thanks advance. :)

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking for a basic Ember.js tutorial? Are you asking how to add numbers?

Comment: Hi @Slaks, Please give me some example for calculate the total amount in each added items in the list, how to create the view and controller for calculate and print the output.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/ http://emberjs.com/guides/views/ http://stackoverflow.com/q/742271/34397

Comment: What do you have so far? Would you attach your code to the question?

Comment: Hi, 

`<p>Total Amount = {{#each product in controller itemController="productsEdit"}}{{product.unitprice}}{{/each}}</p>`

I'm getting output like this :

`Total Amount = 300040003000`

It's merged each item's price, But i need total amount(3000+4000+3000  = 10000).

**How to create the view and controller for this functionality?**

Comment: Would you corresponding JavaScript to the question? It's impossible to give an answer based on the template only.

Comment: `<p>Total Amount = {{#each product in controller itemController="productsEdit"}}{{product.unitprice}}{{/each}}</p>`


I'm getting output like this : Total Amount = 300040003000
It's merged each item's price, <br />
But i need total amount(3000+4000+3000 = 10000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregation methods in [Ember.Enumerables](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html) are handy for this type of thing. I've created a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/UsOGukA/2/edit) demonstrating how to use reduce() in this case. You can create a computed property for the total on your controller that sums the values of each record in your model. Note that passing 0 as the second parameter (initialValue) will seed reduce() with an integer and help you avoid the string concatenation issues you were seeing.

```
  total: function () {
    return this.get('model').reduce(function (previousValue, item, index, enumerable) {
      return previousValue + item.value;
    }, 0);
  }.property('model.@each')
```

(Your second question is unrelated, but you might want to take a look at [jsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf).)

Comment: Hi @Nathan, It's working fine :) thanks.. 

I tried jsPDF, seems complicated to generate the table based output of PDF file. Can you guide me, how to create the table based output pdf file using jsPDF in Emberjs. 

Thanks Advance :)