# HTML to PDF document

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdf

was wondering if there is any way to have the functionality of converting a html page to pdf **without** the need to third party plugins. So in other words just using PHP, Javascript etc or a combination of web based languages.

Comment: php can probably do it, with a third party plugin. You could of course build the "plugin" yourself from scratch to make it non-third party.

Comment: what's the problem with third party plugins ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say this, but in this case a library probably is your best bet. It is possible to write one from scratch, but it's extremely time consuming, since you have to write a function, that renders the HTML/CSS to vector.

Comment: Agreed -- rendering HTML + CSS in *anything* is already a fair tall task ...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by 3rd party. If you want a native js or php function, then, no. There is no such thing. But if you want to use a library, there are a couple.

A quick google search turned up

- http://parall.ax/products/jspdf
- http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/
- [Generating PDF files with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript)
- http://www.fpdf.org/
- http://phptopdf.com/