# Is possible to generate PDF in Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension for Google Chrome and I'm wanting to generate a PDF with a HTML content stored in a variable of the plugin. I thought about using the same system that the browser uses to generate PDF pages, is it possible? How?
Note: I do not want to use a system hosted on a server for it ...

Comment: Maybe [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript) will help.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you don't even need an extension to create a PDF. You can use usual JavaScript in a web page (either with a JS library or not)

You can just use base64 encoding to simply load this URL with the PDF data as DATA:

```
window.location.href="data:application/pdf;base64,DATA"
```

Otherwise, as [blex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913729/blex) mentioned, you can use a library like [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to create something more easily; for example:

```
((new jsPDF()).text(20, 20, 'Hello world.')).save('Test.pdf');
```

Does that satisfy your need?