# How to export asp.net data into PDF with out using ITextsharp?

Tags: asp.net

I want to export my aspx page data into PDF Document without using ITextsharp. Is it possible?
Give me your valuble suggestions.

Comment: Are you asking for a recommendation for a different library or are you wanting to do it without using any external libraries at all? The former is off topic (I believe). The latter may be a bit too broad a question for this site. If something else then please clarify (eg clarify why you want to do it without ITextsharp).

Comment: Exactly,with out using any external libraries i want to generate it.pls help me.How to star

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf), a nice client-side library.

Here's a relevant SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript) that may help you.

Answer (score 1):

For server-side solutions, I can recommend [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/).