# Converting HTML to pdf in GWT Client side

Tags: gwt

Is there a way to convert some html to PDF in GWT Client side 
I have seen some libraries like iText , but they all seem to work on server side .
can i get the PDF without involving any server side work 
is there any possibility

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this JS Library to generate pdf on the client:
https://parall.ax/products/jspdf 
 or look in this SO question:  [Generating PDF files with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript)