# PDF Generation using Jquery

Tags: jquery, pdf, xhtml

I have a fees module.. In that, when I click the download button the fee table automatically converted as a PDF file by using j query. But the output was shown as a table.. I want it as a paragraph view.. How to do that..?

Here is the J query that I've used to converted as a table view in PDF.

```
<script>
    <![CDATA[    
    function generate() {
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontSize(18);
         doc.setFontSize(18);
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 120,0, 40, 20);
        var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("example2"));
for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {  
doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data ,{
            tableWidth: '600',
        headerStyles: {rowHeight: 7, fontSize: 9,valign: 'middle' },
        bodyStyles: {rowHeight: 7, fontSize: 8, valign: 'middle'},
        startY:30,

         theme: 'grid',overflow: 'linebreak'

        });



            }
        doc.save("fee-report_#{collect.regno}.pdf");

    };

</script>
```

Comment: Yes you can generate by JS.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript

Comment: As i know jsPDF not working with css.

Comment: You can use the jsPDF, but as @BharatPatidar said, Css won't work, you need to place everything by coordinates. Also you can use MPDF as a server side pdf generator(using php) and there you can define a css for it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Anyway I've sorted out the problem.

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer or edit your question?