# JQGgrid- How to generate a pdf / excel file from the grid data

Tags: json, ajax, jqgrid

I have the following JQGrid table, which is being generated from JSON data. I want to be able to generate/export or create a pdf file based on the table data state that is view able. I am using JSON , Jqgrid and Javascript

How do I generate a pdf file from the data ?
[Here My FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/615qovew/77/)

JS CODE

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var jsonData = {
          "Name": "Julie Brown",
          "Account": "C0010",
          "LoanApproved": "12/5/2015",
          "LastActivity": "4/1/2016",
          "PledgedPortfolio": "4012214.00875",
          "MaxApprovedLoanAmt": "2050877.824375",
          "LoanBalance": "1849000",
          "AvailableCredit": "201877.824375",
          "Aging": "3",
          "Brokerage": "My Broker",
          "Contact": "Robert L. Johnson",
          "ContactPhone": "(212) 902-3614",
          "RiskCategory": "Yellow",
          "rows": [{
            "ClientID": "C0010",
            "Symbol": "WEC",
            "Description": "Western Electric Co",
            "ShareQuantity": "20638",
            "SharePrice": "21.12",
            "TotalValue": "435874.56",
            "LTVCategory": "Equities",
            "LTVRatio": "50%",
            "MaxLoanAmt": "217937.28"
          }, {
            "ClientID": "C0010",
            "Symbol": "BBB",
            "Description": "Bins Breakers and Boxes",
            "ShareQuantity": "9623",
            "SharePrice": "74.29125",
            "TotalValue": "714904.69875",
            "LTVCategory": "Equities",
            "LTVRatio": "50%",
            "MaxLoanAmt": "357452.349375"
          }, {
            "ClientID": "C0010",
            "Symbol": "GPSC",
            "Description": "Great Plains Small Cap Stock",
            "ShareQuantity": "49612",
            "SharePrice": "14.24",
            "TotalValue": "706474.88",
            "LTVCategory": "Mutual Funds - Small Cap",
            "LTVRatio": "40%",
            "MaxLoanAmt": "282589.952"
          }]
        },
        mmddyyyy = "";
      /*********************************************************************/


      $("#output").jqGrid({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        mtype: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        postData: {
              json: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
        },
        colModel: [
          /**    { name: 'ClientID', label:'ClientID',width: 80, key: true },****/
          {
            name: 'Symbol',
            width: 65
          }, {
            name: 'Description',
            width: 165
          }, {
            name: 'ShareQuantity',
            align: 'right',
            width: 85,
            classes: "hidden-xs", labelClasses: "hidden-xs",
            formatter: 'currency',
            formatoptions: {
              prefix: " ",
              suffix: " "
            }
          }, {
            name: 'SharePrice',
            label: 'Share Price',
            align: 'right',
            width: 100,
            classes: "hidden-xs", labelClasses: "hidden-xs",
            template: "number",
            formatoptions: {
              prefix: " $",
              decimalPlaces: 4
            }
          },
          /*{ label: 'Value1', 
                      name: 'Value1', 
                      width: 80, 
                      sorttype: 'number', 
                      formatter: 'number',
                      align: 'right'
                  }, */
          {
            name: 'TotalValue',
            label: 'Total Value',
            width: 160,
            sorttype: 'number',
            align: "right",
            search: false,
            formatter: 'currency',
            formatoptions: {
              prefix: " $",
              suffix: " "
            }
          }, {
            name: 'LTVRatio',
            label: 'LTV Ratio',
            width: 70,
            sorttype: 'number',
            align: "right",
            formatter: 'percentage',
            formatoptions: {
              prefix: " ",
              suffix: " "
            }
          }, {
            name: 'LTVCategory',
            label: 'LTV Category',
            classes: "hidden-xs", labelClasses: "hidden-xs",
            width: 120,
            width: 165
          },

          {
            name: 'MaxLoanAmt',
            label: 'MaxLoanAmount',
            width: 165,
            sorttype: 'number',
            align: "right",
            search: false,
            formatter: 'currency',
            formatoptions: {
              prefix: " $",
              suffix: " "
            }
          }

        ],
        additionalProperties: ["Symbol", "Description"],
        subGrid: true,
        subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowid) {
            var item = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid);
            $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId)).html("Symbol: <em>" + item.Symbol +
                "</em><br/>Description: <em>" + item.Description + "</em>");
        },
        beforeProcessing: function (data) {
            var symbolsMap = {}, symbolsValues = ":All", rows = data.rows, i, symbol;
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                symbol = rows[i].Symbol;
                if (!symbolsMap.hasOwnProperty(symbol)) {
                    symbolsMap[symbol] = 1;
                    symbolsValues += ";" + symbol + ":" + symbol;
                }
            }
            $(this).jqGrid("setColProp", 'Symbol', {
                stype: "select",
                searchoptions: {
                    value: symbolsValues
                }
            }).jqGrid('destroyFilterToolbar')
            .jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
                stringResult: true,
                searchOnEnter: false,
                defaultSearch : "cn"
            });
        },
        /*beforeProcessing: function (data) {
            var item, i, n = data.length;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                item = data[i];
                item.Quantity = parseFloat($.trim(item.Quantity).replace(",", ""));
                item.LTVRatio = parseFloat($.trim(item.LTVRatio *10000).replace(",", ""));
                item.Value = parseFloat($.trim(item.Value).replace(",", ""));
                item.Num1 = parseInt($.trim(item.Num1).replace(",", ""), 10);
                item.Num2 = parseInt($.trim(item.Num2).replace(",", ""), 10);
            }
        }, */
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        loadonce: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        cmTemplate: {
          autoResizable: true,
          editable: true
        },
        autoResizing: {
          compact: true
        },
        autowidth: true,
        height: 'auto',
        forceClientSorting: true,
        sortname: "Symbol",
        footerrow: true,
        caption: "<b>Collateral Value</b> <span class='pull-right' style='margin-right:20px;'>Valuation as of: " + mmddyyyy + "</span>",
        loadComplete: function() {
          var $self = $(this),
            sum = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "Price", false, "sum"),
            sum1 = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "MaxLoanAmt", false, "sum");
          //ltvratio =  $self.jqGrid("getCol","LTVRatio:addas", "Aved Loan Amount");
          $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {
            LTVCategory: "Max Approved Loan Amount:",
            Price: sum,
            MaxLoanAmt: sum1
          });
        }
      });

      $("#output").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch : "cn"});

        $(window).on("resize", function () {
            var newWidth = $("#output").closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width();
            $("#output").jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);
        }).triggerHandle("resize");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in method to export jqgrid data to pdf. You have to use third party tools( I personally like iTextSharp which can be downloaded from  [Here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) . You have to create action method for printing the grid data in your controller.

[Here](http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/grid/exportpdf)  is also another one example one guy made.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/608173/jQGrid-PDF-Export)  is also another example in trirand. If you see the source code they are using iTextHsarp.
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using JQGridMVCExamples.Models;
    using Trirand.Web.Mvc;
    using System.IO;

```
// 
// For PDF export we are using the free open-source iTextSharp library.
//
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.Data;


namespace JQGridMVCExamples.Controllers.Grid
{
    public partial class GridController : Controller
    {
        // This is the default action for the View. Use it to setup your grid Model.
        public ActionResult ExportPDF()
        {
            // Get the model (setup) of the grid defined in the /Models folder.
            var gridModel = new OrdersJqGridModel();
            var ordersGrid = gridModel.OrdersGrid;

            // Setting the DataUrl to an action (method) in the controller is required.
            // This action will return the data needed by the grid
            ordersGrid.DataUrl = Url.Action("PDFGrid_DataRequested");

            // customize the default Orders grid model with custom settings
            // NOTE: you need to call this method in the action that fetches the data as well,
            // so that the models match
            SetPDFExportGrid(ordersGrid);

            // Pass the custmomized grid model to the View
            return View(gridModel);
        }

        // This method is called when the grid requests data        
        public JsonResult PDFGrid_DataRequested()
        {
            // Get both the grid Model and the data Model
            // The data model in our case is an autogenerated linq2sql database based on Northwind.
            var gridModel = new OrdersJqGridModel();
            var northWindModel = new NorthwindDataContext();

            // customize the default Orders grid model with our custom settings
            SetPDFExportGrid(gridModel.OrdersGrid);

            // Save the current grid state in Session
            // We will later need it for PDF Export
            JQGridState gridState = gridModel.OrdersGrid.GetState();
            Session["gridState"] = gridState;

            // return the result of the DataBind method, passing the datasource as a parameter
            // jqGrid for ASP.NET MVC automatically takes care of paging, sorting, filtering/searching, etc

            return gridModel.OrdersGrid.DataBind(northWindModel.Orders);
        }

        public JsonResult PDFExport_AutoCompleteShipName(string term)
        {
            var northWindModel = new NorthwindDataContext();
            JQAutoComplete autoComplete = new JQAutoComplete();

            autoComplete.DataField = "ShipName";
            autoComplete.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.BeginsWith;
            autoComplete.DataSource = from o in northWindModel.Orders
                                      select o;
            return autoComplete.DataBind();
        }

        private void SetPDFExportGrid(JQGrid ordersGrid)
        {
            // show the search toolbar
            ordersGrid.ToolBarSettings.ShowSearchToolBar = true;
            ordersGrid.ToolBarSettings.ShowSearchButton = true;

            var orderDateColumn = ordersGrid.Columns.Find(c => c.DataField == "OrderDate");
            orderDateColumn.DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}";
            orderDateColumn.SearchType = SearchType.DatePicker;
            orderDateColumn.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
            orderDateColumn.SearchControlID = "DatePicker";
            orderDateColumn.SearchToolBarOperation = SearchOperation.IsEqualTo;

            var shipNameColumn = ordersGrid.Columns.Find(c => c.DataField == "ShipName");
            shipNameColumn.SearchType = SearchType.AutoComplete;
            shipNameColumn.DataType = typeof(string);
            shipNameColumn.SearchControlID = "AutoComplete";
            shipNameColumn.SearchToolBarOperation = SearchOperation.Contains;

            var orderIDColumns = ordersGrid.Columns.Find(c => c.DataField == "OrderID");
            orderIDColumns.Searchable = true;
            orderIDColumns.DataType = typeof(int);
            orderIDColumns.SearchToolBarOperation = SearchOperation.IsEqualTo;

            SetPDFCustomerIDSearchDropDown(ordersGrid);
            SetPDFFreightSearchDropDown(ordersGrid);
        }

        private void SetPDFCustomerIDSearchDropDown(JQGrid ordersGrid)
        {
            // setup the grid search criteria for the columns
            JQGridColumn customersColumn = ordersGrid.Columns.Find(c => c.DataField == "CustomerID");
            customersColumn.Searchable = true;

            // DataType must be set in order to use searching
            customersColumn.DataType = typeof(string);
            customersColumn.SearchToolBarOperation = SearchOperation.IsEqualTo;
            customersColumn.SearchType = SearchType.DropDown;

            // Populate the search dropdown only on initial request, in order to optimize performance
            if (ordersGrid.AjaxCallBackMode == AjaxCallBackMode.RequestData)
            {
                var northWindModel = new NorthwindDataContext();
                var searchList = from customers in northWindModel.Customers
                                 select new SelectListItem
                                 {
                                     Text = customers.CustomerID,
                                     Value = customers.CustomerID
                                 };

                customersColumn.SearchList = searchList.ToList<SelectListItem>();
                customersColumn.SearchList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "All", Value = "" });
            }
        }

        private void SetPDFFreightSearchDropDown(JQGrid ordersGrid)
        {
            // setup the grid search criteria for the columns
            JQGridColumn freightColumn = ordersGrid.Columns.Find(c => c.DataField == "Freight");
            freightColumn.Searchable = true;

            // DataType must be set in order to use searching
            freightColumn.DataType = typeof(decimal);
            freightColumn.SearchToolBarOperation = SearchOperation.IsGreaterOrEqualTo;
            freightColumn.SearchType = SearchType.DropDown;

            // Populate the search dropdown only on initial request, in order to optimize performance
            if (ordersGrid.AjaxCallBackMode == AjaxCallBackMode.RequestData)
            {
                List<SelectListItem> searchList = new List<SelectListItem>();
                searchList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "> 10", Value = "10" });
                searchList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "> 30", Value = "30" });
                searchList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "> 50", Value = "50" });
                searchList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "> 100", Value = "100" });

                freightColumn.SearchList = searchList.ToList<SelectListItem>();
                freightColumn.SearchList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "All", Value = "" });
            }
        }

        public ActionResult ExportToPDF(string exportType)
        {            
            var gridModel = new OrdersJqGridModel();
            var northWindModel = new NorthwindDataContext();
            var grid = gridModel.OrdersGrid;

            // Get the last grid state the we saved before in Session in the DataRequested action
            JQGridState gridState = Session["GridState"] as JQGridState;

            // Need to set grid options again
            SetExportGrid(grid);

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(exportType))
                exportType = "1";

            DataTable exportData;
            switch (exportType)
            {
                case "1":
                    grid.ExportSettings.ExportDataRange = ExportDataRange.All;
                    exportData = grid.GetExportData(northWindModel.Orders);
                    ExportToPDF(exportData);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    grid.ExportSettings.ExportDataRange = ExportDataRange.Filtered;
                    exportData = grid.GetExportData(northWindModel.Orders, gridState);
                    ExportToPDF(exportData);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    grid.ExportSettings.ExportDataRange = ExportDataRange.FilteredAndPaged;
                    exportData = grid.GetExportData(northWindModel.Orders, gridState);
                    ExportToPDF(exportData);
                    break;
            }

            return View();
        }

        private void ExportToPDF(DataTable dt)
        {
            // 
            // For PDF export we are using the free open-source iTextSharp library.
            //

            Document pdfDoc = new Document();
            MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, pdfStream);

            pdfDoc.Open();//Open Document to write
            pdfDoc.NewPage();

            Font font8 = FontFactory.GetFont("ARIAL", 7);

            PdfPTable PdfTable = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
            PdfPCell PdfPCell = null;

            //Add Header of the pdf table
            for (int column = 0; column < dt.Columns.Count; column++)
            {
                PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dt.Columns[column].Caption, font8)));
                PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);
            }

            //How add the data from datatable to pdf table
            for (int rows = 0; rows < dt.Rows.Count; rows++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < dt.Columns.Count; column++)
                {
                    PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dt.Rows[rows][column].ToString(), font8)));
                    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);
                }
            }

            PdfTable.SpacingBefore = 15f; // Give some space after the text or it may overlap the table            
            pdfDoc.Add(PdfTable); // add pdf table to the document
            pdfDoc.Close();
            pdfWriter.Close();

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=gridexport.pdf");
            Response.BinaryWrite(pdfStream.ToArray());
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using JAVA or .NET. I am using JavaScript and JSON to create the JQgrid tables. Is there a way to create the PDF and excel file from the client side using JQgrid or any third part API i can use to generate the pdf and excel files based on the  jqgrid table?

Comment: You can use the [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/778897/3038042) for how to do it just using javascript.