# java Script download function for a specific parts of a html page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using php mysql in my html page. Already I have use many div in my page. I have create a print button, and it print my specific div but now I want to use a download button and it download my specific div data as a `PDF`.

How can it possible?

Comment: write that print code on click of print button thats it ? what's the problem ? have you tried ?

Comment: like print page but i want to save it as a pdf .I try it but can't do it .please help me

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. In future consider adding some demonstration code to your questions. It will help people to answer your question faster.

Comment: This question is similar to yours and has several highly voted answers with suggestions of how to create PDF files with JavaScript in an html document. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

[jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)  would be a greate choice for handling this kind of functionality.  It's relatively easy and quick to use.  Here's a jsfiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/nfnneil/aajsr6vn/2/

## Usage

I used `doc.fromHTML($('#saveThis').html(), 10, 10, {})` and I think that deserves some explanation.  Firstly, doc is a jsPDF object that we are using.  Arguments goes as follows: `HTML content for pdf`, `padding-x in pdf`, `padding-y in pdf`, and then, finally the settings `{}`.

## The code

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<div id="downloadThis">
     Rich html <b>features</b> here.
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="download">generate PDF</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#download').click(function () {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.fromHTML($('#downloadThis').html(), 10, 10, {
        'elementHandlers': {}
    });
    doc.save('download.pdf');
});
```

Comment: **nice ...Thanks Brother**

Comment: Hey, could you by chance mark as answer, it helps a lot. And, no problem.

Comment: What do you mean?  You posted no css; it's probably just conflicting selectors.  So just rename the ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="content">
 <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

 <p>a pararaph</p>
 </div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
 <script>
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
'#editor': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
}
 };

  $('#cmd').click(function () {
  doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
 });
</script>
```

For downloading ....^

Comment: All the function are ok . but css does not work . how can i improve my style.please help

Comment: what css ? where ??? i think  you are makingany mistakein classes names   or anything similar....