# Convert jQuery Data to PDF/Email

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, pdf, report

I wrote some jQuery to create a survey that outputs a somewhat complex report. The report is a mix of scores grabbed from variables and also content that I have appended to HTML elements (using jQuery).

The report displays nicely on my website. Now, I want to allow users to download it to a PDF. I'm on a wordpress site, so I've tried just about every plugin out there that converts a page to PDF file, yet they always look terrible and never grab my jQuery variables or appended content.

Is there some sort of simple script I can write that also grabs the variables/appended content and adds it to a PDF or Email?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript

Comment: I am guessing you want your pdf to look like how its being displayed on your webpage. Tricky work

Answer (score 0):

There are several pdf generators using javascript.

- https://parall.ax/products/jspdf
- http://pdfmake.org/#/

usage is pretty straightforward.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty extensive experience using pdfmake like ThomasK mentioned and I will say that although it is very nice to use, pdf generation is always a pain. I have made hundreds of PDF reports with pdfMake and I have a good strategy.

The key is viewing your data like a large table using 2D arrays. Javascript makes working with arrays easy, so if you're comfortable with js you could just use the `.push()` method onto one large 2D array and then have a button that runs a function that creates `docDefinition` and then runs `pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open()`.

Treat each array within the array as a row, and each item within the sub array as a column.

Check out the pdfMake playground and their docs are pretty good too.