# Form Data to PDF with complex design

Tags: html, css, pdf

I need to create a webpage that will generate PDFs populated with tickets using data from a form.

I'm a beginner and only know a bit of HTML and CSS and don't really know how to approach this.

Here are some of my requirements for this project:

- I'd like to be able to run this offline directly from the HTML file
- I need the PDF to be populated with 10 evenly sized tickets with the same information (5 rows, 2 columns)
- The tickets need to look good, I'd like to be able to use CSS to format them
- I need this to be as simple for the user as inputting information and pressing submit to receive a PDF file to print or email
- I would also like the tickets to have a logo displayed by default

Comment: You'll have to use php or javascript to generate your pdfs. If you are only going to be using an html file, then javascript is your best bet. Here's a previous question discussing it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript

Comment: Use HTML2FPDF .