# pdfkit Browser - "Uncaught ReferenceError: fs is not defined" when using custom fonts

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, arabic-support, node-pdfkit

This question may be asked previously but they have no answer. I try to create a pdf file using `pdfkit` library with Arabic language support. So, first I downloaded a prebuilt version of pdfkit (which is assumed to work in browser) from [here](https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/releases).

Then I wrote this code for adding an Arabic font (like in the [docs](http://pdfkit.org/docs/text.html))

```
const doc = new PDFDocument;
var text_arabic = "مرحبا مَرْحَبًا";

// Using a TrueType font (.ttf)   
doc.font('./trado.ttf')   // --> this line gives the error.
   .text(text_arabic)
   .moveDown(0.5);
```

The  error is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fs is not defined
at Object.fontkit.openSync (pdfkit.js:10949)
at Function.PDFFont.open (pdfkit.js:451)
at PDFDocument.font (pdfkit.js:2227)
at main.js:22
```

pdfkit.js from line 10949:

```
fontkit.openSync = function (filename, postscriptName) {
   var buffer = fs.readFileSync(filename);    / --> error
   return fontkit.create(buffer, postscriptName);
};
```

So, I think 'fs' belongs to node.js part with `require('fs')` but anyway I don't know the solution. What is the solution then? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple solution;

1. Don't forget to add pre-built pdfkit.js and blob-stream.js files
2. Copy below js code and include it in your html
3. Put your fonts to the same place with html/js (like trado.ttf)
4. Change the `getFont(...)` according to your font name

Done!

**Important Notes:**

1. If you run it without any server, chrome will give CORS policy error. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45433997/4176989) to disable just for try)
2. When you move your files to a server, or running in local server, there will be no CORS error.
3. Last and most importantly, give some times to `xhr.onload`. Because of that we create `writeToPDF()` function seperately for using with a button after loading.

```js
const doc = new PDFDocument;
const stream = doc.pipe(blobStream());

var embeddedFonts = (function() {
  var fontCollection = {};

  function getFont(name, src) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', src, true);
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.onload = function(evt) {
      var arrayBuffer = xhr.response;

      if (arrayBuffer) {
        fontCollection[name] = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        registerEmbeddedFonts(doc, embeddedFonts);

      } else {
        error = "Error downloading font resource from " + src;
      }

    };
    xhr.send(null);
  }

  getFont("Trado", 'trado.ttf');

  return fontCollection;
}());

function registerEmbeddedFonts(doc, fontCollection) {
  doc.registerFont("Trado", fontCollection["Trado"]);
}

function writeToPDF() {
  doc.fontSize(40);
  doc.font('Trado').text('مَرْحَبًا');

  doc.end();
  stream.on('finish', function() {
    // get a blob you can do whatever you like with
    const blob = stream.toBlob('application/pdf');


    // or get a blob URL for display in the browser
    const url = stream.toBlobURL('application/pdf');
    var frame = document.getElementById("pdfFrame");

    frame.src = url;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/releases/download/v0.8.0/pdfkit.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/devongovett/blob-stream/releases/download/v0.1.3/blob-stream.js"></script>


<iframe id="pdfFrame" src="" width="300" height="300"> </iframe>
<button type="button" onclick="writeToPDF();">Write to PDF</button>

<!-- This example doesn't work because of missing trado.ttf font file.
Try to run at your PC -->
```

Comment: i tried this. and even pdfkit.standalone.js. I always get Uncaught ReferenceError: fs is not defined

Comment: Did you disable CORS policy on chrome? Do you get any other errors?