# How to edit and create a text/pdf file using javascript(if not possible then any other language)?

Tags: javascript, file, web, text

I am trying to create an online CV maker.I intend to use HTML form to get input from user and then put this text into a template/file.
I am not able to figure out that how can i do so using JavaScript?
Please guide me,Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript ?

Comment: Thanks for your help.Can you please let me know how can i import my data(input taken from user using html form) to the solutions offered in the answers.Sorry this is the first time i am working with data or files.

Answer (score 1):

First, in javascript you can get your input from the HTML by using javascript/JQuery

`var input = document.getelementbyid("#id").value`

or

`var input = $("#id").val()`

Then proceed like explained in the example of the topic ([Generating PDF files with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript))

```
var doc = new jsPDF()

doc.text(input, 10, 10)
doc.save('a4.pdf')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i am  new to this so will try and respond soon

Comment: Use an id for each input of your form -> Upon validation, get the value(s) with JS or Jquery using the id(s) of the input(s) -> Generate the PDF using the jsPDF library