# How to use Hopding / pdf-lib with pure javascript? (Without using a package manager)

Tags: javascript, pdf-lib.js

How can I use [Hopding/pdf-lib](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib) with pure javascript without using node or any other package manager?

I have noticed that they have mentioned [supporting pure JavaScript](https://pdf-lib.js.org/). But not mentioned how?

[image]

> I searched and I found the answer myself, it took long. So I decided to
> put it here so that anyone can refer it faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **UMD Module** as mentioned in their GitHub page. Here are some of the useful information I extracted from their GitHub page.

**UMD Module**

You can also download pdf-lib as a UMD module from unpkg or jsDelivr. The UMD builds have been compiled to ES5, so they should work in any modern browser. UMD builds are **useful if you aren't using a package manager or module bundler**. For example, **you can use them directly in the  tag** of an HTML page.

The following builds are available:

- https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.js
- https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js
- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.js
- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js

NOTE: if you are using the CDN scripts in production, you should include a specific version number in the URL, for example:

- https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib@1.4.0/dist/pdf-lib.min.js
- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib@1.4.0/dist/pdf-lib.min.js

**Example**:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="display: flex; width: 100%; height: 100%; flex-direction: column; overflow: hidden;">
        <iframe id="pdf" style="flex-grow: 1; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib@1.17.1/dist/pdf-lib.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    createPdf();
    async function createPdf() {
      const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
      const page = pdfDoc.addPage([350, 400]);
      page.moveTo(110, 200);
      page.drawText('Hello World!');
      const pdfDataUri = await pdfDoc.saveAsBase64({ dataUri: true
     });
      document.getElementById('pdf').src = pdfDataUri;
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Here key is to note "PDFLib." part. We can access all the PDFLib functions as PDFLib.PDFDocument.create() or PDFLib.StandardFonts.TimesRoman or PDFLib.rgb(0, 0.53, 0.71) etc