# Html/Javascript - Survey, produce results and create pdf

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am starting to code in HTML and JavaScript and need some help!
I am creating a program to survey people and am having an issue creating the results and how to create a pdf with all the questions and answers with the results. I have the form completed but when I press the results I need help because I do not see any results when I press the results button. Also, how do I create a pdf with all this information.

Thanks for your patience!
Kevin

I can complete the form, but there are no results

```
Here is the code: 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Health Assessment</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function displayQuestion(answer) {
  document.getElementById(answer + 'Question').style.display = "block";

  if (answer == "yes") { // hide the div that is not selected
    document.getElementById('noQuestion').style.display = "none";
  } else if (answer == "no") {
    document.getElementById('yesQuestion').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function displayQuestion3(answer) {

  document.getElementById(answer + 'Question3').style.display = "block";

  if (answer == "yes") { // hide the div that is not selected
    document.getElementById('noQuestion3').style.display = "none";
  } else if (answer == "no") {
    document.getElementById('yesQuestion3').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function displayQuestion4(answer) {

  document.getElementById(answer + 'Question4').style.display = "block";

  if (answer == "yes") { // hide the div that is not selected
    document.getElementById('noQuestion4').style.display = "none";
  } else if (answer == "no") {
    document.getElementById('yesQuestion4').style.display = "none";
  }
}

</script>

<h2>Health Assessment</h2>

<form id="surveyForm">
     <div class="form-control">
     <label for="name" id="label-name">
        Name
     </label>
     <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" />
        Date <input type='date' id='hasta' value='<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>
   </div>

     <br>
     <div class="form-control">
     <label for="csl" id="label-csl">
        Age? 
     </label>
     <select name="csl" id="csl">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="5">60+</option>
        <option value="4">50-60</option>
        <option value="3">30-40</option>
        <option value="2">20-30</option>
        <option value="1">10-20</option>
        <option value="0">Rather not say</option>
     </select>
   </div>
  
   <br> 
   Question 1: Were you an athele?
      <label><input type="radio" id="yes" name="yesOrNo" value="yes" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" id="no" name="yesOrNo" value="no" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />No</label>
   <br>
  
   <div id="noQuestion" style="display:none;">
   </div>
  
   <div id="yesQuestion" style="display:none; padding-left:2em;">
      In either of these? <br>
        In high school?
         <label><input type="radio" name="q1a" value="1"> Yes</label>
         <label><input type="radio" name="q1a" value="2"> No</label><br>
      In college?
         <label><input type="radio" name="q1b" value="1"> Yes</label>
         <label><input type="radio" name="q1b" value="2"> No</label>
   </div>

   <br>
   Question 2: Did you have any post college atheletics?
      <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="1"> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="2"> No</label>
   <br>

   <br>
   Question 3: Did you have any injuries? 
      <label><input type="radio" id="yes" name="yesOrNo3" value="yes" onchange="displayQuestion3(this.value)" />Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" id="no" name="yesOrNo3" value="no" onchange="displayQustion3(this.value)" />No</label>
   <br>
   
   <div id="noQuestion3" style="display:none;">
   </div>
  
   <div id="yesQuestion3" style="display:none; padding-left:2em;">
      In either of these? <br>
           a. In high school ?
           <label><input type="radio" name="q3a" value="1"> Yes</label>
           <label><input type="radio" name="q3a" value="2"> No</label><br>
         b. In college?
           <label><input type="radio" name="q3b" value="1"> Yes</label>
           <label><input type="radio" name="q3b" value="2"> No</label>
   </div>

   <br>
   Question 4: Have you had any surgeries?
      <label><input type="radio" id="yes" name="yesOrNo4" value="yes" onchange="displayQuestion4(this.value)" />Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" id="no" name="yesOrNo4" value="no" onchange="displayQuestion4(this.value)" />No</label>
   <br>
 
   <div id="noQuestion4" style="display:none;">
   </div> 
   
   <div id="yesQuestion4" style="display:none; padding-left:2em;">
      In either of these? <br>
         a. In high school?
           <label><input type="radio" name="q4a" value="1"> Yes</label>
           <label><input type="radio" name="q4a" value="2"> No</label><br>
         b. In college?
           <label><input type="radio" name="q4b" value="1"> Yes</label>
           <label><input type="radio" name="q4b" value="2"> No</label>
   </div>

  <br>
  Question 5: Do you injuries prohibit you from normal activities?
     <label><input type="radio" name="q5" value="1"> Yes</label>
     <label><input type="radio" name="q5" value="2"> No</label><br>

  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="calculateScore()">Results</button>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
  function calculateScore() {
    const form = document.getElementById('surveyForm');
    const q1aValue = parseInt(form.querySelector('input[name="q1a"]:checked').value);
    const q1bValue = parseInt(form.querySelector('input[name="q1b"]:checked').value);
    const q2Value = parseInt(form.querySelector('input[name="q2"]:checked').value);
    const q3avalue = parseInt(form.querySelector('input[name="q3a"]:checked').value);
    const q3bValue = parseInt(form.querySelector('input[name="q3b"]:checked').value);
    const q4aValue = parseInt(form.querySelector('input[name="q4a"]:checked').value);
    const q4bValue = parseInt(form.querySelector('input[name="q4b"]:checked').value);
    const q5Value = parseInt(form.querySelector('input[name="q5"]:checked').value);

    const totalScore = q1aValue + q1bValue + q2Value + q3aValue + q3bValue + q4aValue + q4bValue + q52Value;

    let resultText = 'Based on your answers, ';
    if (totalScore < 4) {
      resultText += 'consider exploring more outdoor activities.';
    } else if (totalScore >= 4 && totalScore < 6) {
      resultText += 'continue exercising regularly for better health.';
    } else {
      resultText += 'you seem to have a healthy lifestyle!';
    }

    const q2Text = form.querySelector('input[name="q2"]:checked').parentNode.innerText;
    const q5Text = form.querySelector('input[name="q5"]:checked').parentNode.innerText;

    const summary = `Question 1: ${q1Text.trim()}, Answer: ${form.querySelector('input[name="q2"]:checked').value}\nQuestion 2: ${q2Text.trim()}, Answer: ${form.querySelector('input[name="q5"]:checked').value}\nSummary: ${resultText}`;

    document.getElementById('result').innerText = summary;
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hit F12. Check the errors in the console of your browser's dev tools.

Comment: Hint: if you want to get the value of an element, you first have to make sure that the element is present.

Answer (score 1):

Question 3's second input has a typo in the onchange:

```js
onchange="displayQustion3(this.value)"
```

`displayQustion3` should be `displayQuestion3`

On this line you have more typos:

```js
const totalScore = q1aValue + q1bValue + q2Value + q3aValue + q3bValue + q4aValue + q4bValue + q52Value;
```

`q3aValue` should be `q3avalue` (or alternatively, change the casing of the const a few lines above this one)

`q52Value` should be `q5Value`

Then this line references a variable that doesn't exist:

```js
const summary = `Question 1: ${q1Text.trim()}, Answer: ${form.querySelector('input[name="q2"]:checked').value}\nQuestion 2: ${q2Text.trim()}, Answer: ${form.querySelector('input[name="q5"]:checked').value}\nSummary: ${resultText}`;
```

`q1Text` is not defined. Judging by the rest of your code it should be defined above this line as

```js
const q1Text = form.querySelector('input[name="yesOrNo"]:checked').parentNode.innerText;
```

All these mistakes were simple to find because they were all logged as errors when testing/fixing your code in the browser's [developer console](https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/), which I highly advise you learn to use in the future. With [console.log](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_log.asp) you can print out values of variables at specific points in your code to verify their correctness while developing/debugging. Becoming proficient in JavaScript debugging is the only way to become a half decent JavaScript coder.

Creating a PDF is a much more involved question.  The answer is usually to use another library that will do all the heavy lifting for you.  See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript), or google JS PDF libraries to learn more.

Comment: OMG!!! thank you so much!!