# Automated QA for auto-generated PDF documents

Tags: pdf, automated-tests, pdf-generation

We are generating lots of PDFs from csv data. We want to have some form of automated QA in place to make sure the PDFs are accurate. A simple example would be: for a given PDF, make sure some text is present on the first page. What tools or libraries could be used to achieve this programmatically?

My preference would be a nodejs solution but I'm open to using other platforms if needed.

Comment: this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript) could be useful

Comment: I don't really think that u have to test the PDF as an output file. I think you will have to test the data used to generate that PDF. Otherwise you will test the PDF generator engine and I think is not the point.

Comment: @DA that was also my original thinking but the process involves multiple tools and steps so there would still be some value to doing an end to end test